# Bootstrap btn-primary blue text

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in my `.aspx` page,
the `btn-primary` show text as blue instead of white.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm"
CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="req" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
OnClick="btnConfirm_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

[image]

but the `btn-default` looks as expected.

What is the problem?
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since I do not prefer all that much of using libraries and nor do I no anything about ASP.net, I do know my way around bootstrap. The best solution is using inline CSS. Make use of the style attribute.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure to use latest version of Twitter Bootstrap.
2. Try change <asp:LinkButton...> to <asp:Button>, because <asp:LinkButton...> will render your control <a> tag, which 's css is defined by Bootstrap as

   a 
   {
       color: #337ab7; /* This is the color of your Confirm button */
       ...
   }

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Google Chrome inspect tool (or something like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) extention on Firefox) and tracing the CSS rules that gives the text this blue color. 
[Here's some info on how to use inspect tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSS is overwriting the text colour value with blue text.

Have a look at the page with the Developer tools and look at the CSS for the element. These things are usually easy to find and fix.